# Having Trouble passing a Cell object? (i could be wrong)

Tags: excel, vba

First off thank you very much. Over the last few months (i believe) my coding has progressed drastically. Any and all criticize is always welcome (rip me apart).

Recently I started to try to use different Subs (I dont quite understand when to use functions etc, but i figure it is good structure practice for when i figure it out.

I am hitting a Run-time 424 Error with the following bit of code in Sub ownerCHECK

```
Sub OccupationNORMALIZATION()

    Dim infoBX As String

    ' initialize variables
    LRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    LCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    STATUScounter = LRow

        Do While infoBX = ""
            infoBX = InputBox("Enter Occupation Column", "Occupation Column")
        Loop

              restaurCHECK (infoBX)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub
```

-

```
Sub restaurCHECK(infoBX As String)
    Dim RestaurantS(), RestaurantDQs() As Variant
    Dim i, LRow, LCol, STATUScounter As Long
    Dim rRng As Range

        LRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        LCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        STATUScounter = LRow
RestaurantS = Array("estaur", "food", "cafe", "beverage", "waiter", "waitr", _
                "waitstaff", "wait staff", "grill") 'array list of target occupations


RestaurantDQs = Array("fast", "pub", "import", "packing", "processing", "packag", _
                "retired", "anufact", "distrib") ' disqualifying words for Restaurante category

Set rRng = Range(infoBX & "2:" & infoBX & LRow)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each cell In rRng
        ownerCHECK (cell)
        For i = LBound(RestaurantS) To UBound(RestaurantS)
                If InStrRev(cell.Value, UCase(RestaurantS(i))) > 0 Then
                    cell.Offset(, 1) = "Restaurants"
                    cell.Interior.Color = 52479
                End If
            Debug.Print cell.Value
        Next

        For i = LBound(RestaurantDQs) To UBound(RestaurantDQs)
            If InStrRev(cell.Value, UCase(RestaurantDQs(i))) And cell.Interior.Color = 52479 Then
                cell.Interior.Color = 255
                cell.Offset(, 1) = ""


            End If

        Next

                    STATUScounter = STATUScounter - 1
                    Application.StatusBar = "REMAINING ROWS " & STATUScounter & "           tristram "

    Next cell


End Sub
```

-

```
Sub ownerCHECK(str_owner As Range)
   Dim owner() As Variant
   owner() = Array("owner", "shareholder", "owns ")
        For i = LBound(owner) To UBound(owner)
                If InStrRev(str_owner, UCase(owner(i))) > 0 Then
                    cell.Offset(, 2) = "Owner"

                End If
        Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of issues in ownerCHECK():

- "cell" is not defined (unless it's global)
- you shouldn't use "cell" as a variable name (internal VBA property)
- check validity of incoming range

.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ownerCHECK(ByRef rngOwner As Range)

    If Not rngOwner Is Nothing Then

        Dim owner() As Variant
        owner() = Array("OWNER", "SHAREHOLDER", "OWNS ")

        For i = LBound(owner) To UBound(owner)
            If InStrRev(UCase(rngOwner), owner(i)) > 0 Then
                rngOwner.Offset(, 2) = "Owner"
            End If
        Next

    End If

End Sub
```